# Asp.net mvc with or without ORM

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, orm

Soon i will be starting to work on a small to medium web project. I will be the only developer to work on this project. So i am looking for pointers towards some design decisions/tools/technology. I would like to use asp.net MVC for this web project (the reason being this project has got good chance to grow a lot, therefore thinking more maintainable).

We use oracle as our backend and configured enterprise application data access block to use with odp.net and seems to have worked well. But all of our previous projects were typically asp.net web forms/windows forms.

So with mvc, is it better to use ORM like nhibernate than DAAB?
I have gone through [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178359.aspx) article, but still confused.. Thanks

Comment: This is really not the type of question for SO.  My own personal experience is with Hibernate+Java with Jboss Seam, and I don't like hibernate.  It obscures too much, has its own HQL dialect you have to learn, etc.  There is no black/white answer.  Not knowing anything about your app's database requirements (#users, lots of editing, data set sizes), it is hard to say. My own view is that you should not treat the database as a "black box" to keep at arm's length.  Oracle is an expensive product, so use it to its fullest.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of enterprise application data access block. I think it's bloated and clumsy. Plus, today, it's somewhat outdated. I'd go with a ORM, either Entity Framework or NHibernate, or write a thin database access layer to simply call Oracle stored procs.